# Adoption of ResponseTree from Ajax is not considered HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mootools

I load an HTML snippet by Ajax and `adopt` it into a container. The elements are being represented correctly. But, I can't run any method on them i.e. any method that should work on an HTML element.

```
var Req = new Request.HTML({'onSuccess':function(responseTree){
$('form').innerHTML='';
$('form').adopt(responseTree);
   $('form').getElemets('ul').each(function(e){e.setStyle('display','none');});
}
}}).get(href);
```

returned html is:

```
<ul><li><span>ssss</span></li></ul>
```

I might have forgotten a parenthesis in this example, but the real code is OK, when I alert the found elements inside the `each` function, I get `[object Element]` and not `[object HTMLUIElement]` as I should

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work perfectly fine to me. See example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/mXmjr/

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: "<ul><li><span>ssss</span></li></ul>"
    },
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(response) {        
        document.body.empty();
        document.body.adopt(response);
        document.body.getElements('ul').each(function(list){
            list.highlight();
        });
    }
}).send();
```